# Remove Gravity From SKNode Floor Class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I've got two rectangles that show up in the beginning of my game but once it starts, gravity takes them down. I've got the code below in a separate "Floor.swift" class. I also have a "BitMaskCategories.swift" file with the info below.

```
let ballCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let avoidCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
let floorCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
let pointCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
let lifeCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
```

And here is my "Floor.swift" class

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Floor: SKNode {
    override init() {
        super.init()

        let leftWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 300))
        leftWall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
        leftWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
        leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftWall.size)
        self.addChild(leftWall)

        let rightWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 300))
        rightWall.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)
       rightWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
        rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rightWall.size)
        self.addChild(rightWall)

        // self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        // self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        // Set the bit mask properties
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = balloonCategory
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = nailDropCategory | pointCategory | lifeCategory
        //self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = balloonCategory
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemted")
    }
}
```

Why do I get the error, "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" but when I use a "?" instead of "!" the app works but the rectangles fall. I need that line in order for them not to do that and I don't even get how this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign: `.isDynamic = false`
before the object initialization,

you should move `leftWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false`

*after* `leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftWall.size)`

and the same for: `rightWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false`, move it

*after*: `rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rightWall.size)`

so your code might be:

```
let leftWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 300))
leftWall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftWall.size)
leftWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
self.addChild(leftWall)

let rightWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 300))
rightWall.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)
rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rightWall.size)
rightWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
self.addChild(rightWall)
```

Comment: I appreciate you so freaking much!

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Yeah! :)

Comment: So one thing led to another problem, I feel like you'll know the solution fairly fast. Check out my new post if you get a chance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946410/skphysicscontact-not-detecting-categorybitmask-collision