# SKPhysicsContact Not Detecting categoryBitMask Collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicscontact

So I have my "Floor.swift" class below which is basically a bunch of walls. I have objects coming from the top of the screen and once the Floor and SKSpriteNodes collide, I'd like the SKSpriteNode to be removed. Below is my Floor class.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

    class Floor: SKNode {
        override init() {
            super.init()

            let leftWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 5, height: 50))
            leftWall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50)
            leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftWall.size)
            leftWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
            self.addChild(leftWall)

            let rightWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 5, height: 50))
            rightWall.position = CGPoint(x: 375, y: 50)
            rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rightWall.size)
            rightWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
            self.addChild(rightWall)

            let bottomWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 10))
            bottomWall.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: -5)
            bottomWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: bottomWall.size)
            bottomWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
            self.addChild(bottomWall)

            // Set the bit mask properties
            self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = floorCategory
            self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = objectCategory | pointCategory | lifeCategory
            self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = dodgeCategory
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemted")
        }
    }
```

Then in my GameScene class under "`func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`" I wrote:

```
 if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == floorCategory) && (contact.bodyB.contactTestBitMask == objectCategory | pointCategory | lifeCategory) {
              contact.bodyB.node!.removeFromParent()
              print("COLLISION")
}
```

But for some reason I'm not getting any detection what's so ever. I made my "Floor" class be a "contactTestBitMask" on each class of my objectCategory, pointCategory, lifeCategory. What am I doing wrong!? My other collisions are detected but not this one.

Answer (score 3):

Your `leftWall`, `rightWall` and `bottomWall` have the default `contactTest` and `collision` bit masks, so will collide with everything and generate contacts with nothing. Except they all have their `isDynamic` property set to `false`, so they can’t collide with or contact anything (although other things can collide and contact them if those other things have `isDynamic` set to `true`).

But this is probably what you want (Floors and walls are usually not dynamic). I suspect the real problem is that objects of `Floor` class won’t have a physics body, unless you initialise it somewhere else. You have these lines:

`self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ...`
`self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ...`
`self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ...`

but you haven't actually created `self.physicsBody`. Your code would crash except you’ve used optional chaining (`self,phyicsBody?`) and so Swift gets to the ‘?’ and says “Oh - it’s optional and doesn’t exist. I’ll just stop here then”

At the very least, try creating a physics body for your `Floor` object using the physics bodies of the 3 wall objects:

`Self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(Bodies: [leftWall.physicsBody, rightWall.PhysicsBoidy, bottomWall.physicsBody])`

(SKPhysicsBody has an initialiser that takes an array of physics bodies to create a new physics body).

Comment: I tried doing "let ourUnionOfBodies = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [leftWall.physicsBody!, rightWall.physicsBody!, bottomWall.physicsBody!])" and following that I wrote on the next line "ourUnionOfBodies.isDynamic = false" but it still doesn't work? I don't see no collision detection they just fall right through

Comment: @Dewan Hi Dewan - sorry for ther late reply  but I was travelling. So you’ve created an `ourUnionOfBodies` physics body, and you’ve set that physics body to be non-dynamic, but have you set this as the Floor object’s physics body anywhere? You’ll still need to do a `self.physicsBody = <some physics body>` before doing any of the `self.physicsBody?...` stuff. Any reason why you’ve created a separate property to hold the physics body rather than just do `self.physicsBody = SkyphysicsBody(bodies...`)?`

Comment: I tried that but it didn’t really make a difference, I did not see collision detection. They kept falling through my Floor

Comment: I think you need to show more code. Specifically the latest version of your Floor class with the `self.physicsBody =` assignment and how you create your object of 'Floor' class and set its contactTest and collision bit masks.